# Zapier Webhook GET request to Zoho Invoice API returns "Please ensure that the invoices has less than 100 characters."

Tags: get, webhooks, zapier, zoho

I am making a get request using a Zapier webhook in my Zap to the Zoho Invoice API at the URL https://invoice.zoho.eu/api/v3/invoices/{invoice_id}. I am passing the invoice ID retrieved from the previous step in the Zap (another GET request to the Zoho Invoices API) but it returns the below error.

Failed to create a request in Webhooks by Zapier
The app returned "Please ensure that the invoices has less than 100 characters.".

When making the GET request locally using postman it returns Status 200 OK along with the invoice data object.

I have searched the [Zoho Invoice API documentation](https://www.zoho.com/invoice/api/v3/introduction/#overview) for this error message but find no reference to it, neither does the Zapier interface display what Status code is being returned, so I am struggling to diagnose this.

If anyone can help it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Since the postman GET returns the invoice and the 200 status, that suggests the 100 characters constraint may be part of the Zapier Webhook.  It would be good to see if Zapier support would have feedback on it if you let them know that the postman GET succeeded where the zapier-webhook didn't.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I got this to work using the Catch Raw Hook event of the Zapier webhook app rather than the standard 'Catch Hook'.

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work using the Catch Raw Hook event of the Zapier webhook app rather than the standard 'Catch Hook'.